# Problema creando un componente con react js

Tags: javascript, laravel, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Estoy tratando de crear un componente con react luego de hacer una consulta post con axios, el tema es que al parecer renderiza el elemento antes de hacer el setState a la variable o antes de realizar incluso el axios. Dejo acá el codigo:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import BtnAdd from './AddButton'; 
import axios from 'axios';

 class Admin extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            productos:null
        };
    }
    async  getProductos(){
      await axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/productos'
            }).then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            var data = response.data;
                this.setState({ productos:data});
            });
    }
    render() {
            this.getProductos();
            const productos = this.state;
        
            return ( productos.map((data, index) => {
                    <tr key={data.id}>
                    <td>{data.nombres}</td>
                    <td>{data.precio}</td>
                    <td>{data.descripcion}</td>
                    <td>{data.imagen}</td>
                    <td>{data.stock}</td>
                    <td>{data.isActive}</td>
                    </tr>
                     }))
               
    }
}
if (document.getElementById('adminTable')){
    ReactDOM.render(<Admin/>, document.getElementById('adminTable'));
}
```

El error que recibo es el siguiente de igual forma: The above error occurred in the  component:
in Admin

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.

Comment: y si pruebas encapsulando tu función `getProductos` dentro de un `componentDidMount` si necesitas que haga la llamada apenas se monte el componente

Answer (score 0):

Debes basarte en el ciclo de vida de un componente fuente: https://es.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

mira en tu codigo deberia ser algo parecido a esto:

```
class Admin extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      getProductos() // aqui podrias hacer la llamada con axios
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
  }

  render() {
            return ( productos.map((data, index) => {
                    <tr key={data.id}>
                   ...

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que estás haciendo una petición de forma asíncrona, y no la estás mandando a llamar, entonces lo primero es llamar a la función getProductos después de renderizarce, con la función **componentDidMount** lo segundo es que en el return debes preguntar primero si el **this.state.productos !== null** para hacer el map una vez existan productos en el estado, de lo contrario estas creando un map en un objeto null, te dejo un ejemplo [Aqui](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-kepler-bh5k0?file=/src/App.js) espero te sirva.